# Is it possible to prove ˫ (A→B) ∨ (B→A) in Statement Logic?

Tags: logic

I initially tried to convert the whole thing into a Conditional via Material Implication but just ended up in a loop of assuming the antecedent and then using DeMorgan's.

If anyone has any insight I would appreciate it.

Comment: Either $A$ or $\neg A$. If $A$ then $B\to A$. If $\neg A$ then $A\to B$.

Comment: If you wanted to convert this to something simpler, it'd be easier to convert the conditionals to $\lor$-s. So you'd get $(\neg A \lor B) \lor (\neg B \lor A)$, which by associativity and commutativity is $(A \lor \neg A) \lor (B \lor \neg B)$, which clearly holds.

Comment: Exactly what formal rules are you allowed to use?  There are literally dozens of different formal system, each with their own rules.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \vdash (A \to B) \vee (B \to A) $$

$
\begin{array}{llll}
\{\emptyset\} & 1. & A \vee \neg A & \text{Theorem Intro: Law of Excluded Middle} \\
\{2\} & 2. & A & \text{Assumption} \\
\{3\} & 3. & B & \text{Assumption for Conditional Proof} \\
\{2,3\} & 4. & A \wedge B & \text{2,3 Conjunction Intro} \\
\{2,3\} & 5. & A & \text{4 Conjunction Elim} \\
\{2\} & 6. & B \to A & \text{3,5 Conditional Proof} \\
\{2\} & 7. & (B \to A) \vee (A \to B) & \text{6 Disjunction Intro} \\
\{2\} & 8. & (A \to B) \vee (B \to A)  & \text{7 Sequent Intro: Commutativity} \\
\{9\} & 9. & \neg A & \text{Assumption} \\
\{10\} & 10. & A & \text{Assumption for Conditional Proof} \\
\{9,10\} & 11. & A \wedge \neg A & \text{9,10 Conjunction Intro} \\
\{9,10\} & 12. & B & \text{11 Sequent Intro: EFQ} \\
\{9\} & 13. & A \to B & \text{10,12 Conditional Proof} \\
\{9\} & 14. & (A \to B) \vee (B \to A) & \text{13 Disjunction Intro} \\
\{\emptyset\} & 15. & (A \to B) \vee (B \to A) & \text{1,2,8,9,14 Disjunction Elim} & \square \\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

First, prove $~A \land  \neg B \implies  [B \implies A]~$ by twice applying conditional proof (lines 1-5).

Then apply definition of  '$\implies$' to obtain $[A \implies B] \lor [B \implies A]~$  (lines 6-9).

Plain-text version:

```
1   A & ~B
    Premise

    2   B
        Premise

    3   A
        Split, 1

4   B => A
    Conclusion, 2

5   A & ~B => [B => A]
    Conclusion, 1

6   ~[A & ~B] | [B => A]
    Imply-Or, 5

7   ~~[A => ~~B] | [B => A]
    Imply-And, 6

8   [A => ~~B] | [B => A]
    Rem DNeg, 7

9   [A => B] | [B => A]
    Rem DNeg, 8
```

HTML version available